# two fields in select field form Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

To create one appointment I need to choice one patient.
In select list I need to show the name and age of patients.

The code:

```
class AppointmentType extends AbstractType{

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('id', 'entity', array('class'=>'ProjectAppointmentBundle:Patient',
            'label'=>'Patient '
        ));

}

public function getName()
{
    return 'patient';
}
```

}

and the action:

```
public function newAction()
{
    ...

    $patient = new Patient();

    $entity = new Appointment($patient);
    $form   = $this->createForm(new AppointmentType(), $entity);

    return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView()
    );
}
```

That is working but show only the name of patient (_toString() method return the name of patient). 
I need show the name and age of patient in select field.

Entity Patient have id,name,age,adress,etc...

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be pleased to hear it's quite easy. All you need to do is pass another option called 'property' to your entity field:

```
$builder->add('id', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'ProjectAppointmentBundle:Patient',
        'label' => 'Patient',
        'property' => 'nameAndAge',
    ));
```

Then in your Patient class add a method called getNameAndAge:

```
public function getNameAndAge()
{
    return $this->name . ' - ' . $this->age;
}
```

You can obviously format the name and age differently to my example.

I hope this helps

Comment: You're very welcome. Wait until you get into using the SonataAdminBundle - very poorly documented!